# Looking for a video player with capability to maintain a long list of Recent Items

Tags: mac, video, mediaplayer

I've tried VLC and MPlayerX and I was disappointed with their "Recent" menu. VLC maintains very little history and it sometimes even randomly erases itself.

I switched to MPlayerX -- it doesn't erase at random, but there are only 6 items in "Recent".

I watch multiple TV series and this lack of more "Recent" history sometimes leads me to lose track of what is the most recent episode I've watched on the particular series.

Does anyone know a video player that supports adjusting that to **25** or more items in it's "Recent" menu

Comment: This is subjective. I would consider a long list for recent videos to be Ten. Others will be different. Please specify what YOU consider a long list.

Comment: Let's say 25 or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Appears that **Quicktime** and **VLC** will have a default of ten (10) items in their 'Open recent' menu.

This can be over ridden by going to the '**General**' system preferences and changing the '**Recent items**'  to either:

- none
- 5
- 10
- 15
- 20
- 30
- 50

[image]

You could also just add your videos **Media Library** in VLC and remove an item once you have watched it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I realize it's a general setting in OS X. I hope it also works on MPlayerX, which I'm currently using. If not, I'll go back to VLC.